# how to show default selected option in select box

Tags: javascript, angular

I have searched similar kind of links ,but no luck.

I have an array of objects which i need to show as a dropdown and i have to select one default option .My object contains value,selected properties.If value and selected properties are matched then it has to be the default selected option.My dropdown Array look like this...

```
[
    {
      "selected": "samsung",
      "resource_Attribute_ID": 486,
      "value": "hp",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "selected": "samsung",
      "resource_Attribute_ID": 486,
      "value": "samsung",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "selected": "samsung",
      "resource_Attribute_ID": 486,
      "value": "dell",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ]
```

and HTML code like this..

```
<select formControlName="controlFordropdwn" >
            <option value="" disabled  hidden>Select</option>
            <option *ngFor="let type of dropdown"   [value]="type.value" [selected]='type.value == type.selected'  >
              {{type.value}}
            </option>
          </select>
```

Any response which is related to this will help me alot.
Thanks to you inAdvance

Comment: your code seems to work. if 'selected' and 'value' are equal, then this option is selected by default. Please tell me if I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Hey, did any of the answers solve your issue? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested your code, but something like this should work:

```
<select formControlName="controlFordropdwn">
    <option *ngIf="type.value == type.selected">{{type.value}}</option> <!--I added this line -->
    <option *ngFor="let type of dropdown" [value]="type.value" [selected]='type.value == type.selected'>
        {{type.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: <option *ngIf="type.value == type.selected">{{type.value}}</option> <!--I added this line --> Here type variable cannot be accessed.so it will not work for me.Thanks alot for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable to store the value being selected. Then when you initialize the component, assign the default value to that variable. Inside your html you need to include `[(ngModel)]`.

*.component.ts

```
public selectedValue: any; //not sure what the value type is

constructor() {
    this.selectedValue = "default value";
}
```

*.component.html

```
<select formControlName="controlFordropdwn" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <option value="" disabled  hidden>Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let type of dropdown" [value]="type.value" [selected]='type.value == type.selected'>
        {{type.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response,but my selectedValue always changes as dropdown array will be itarated.Please give me solution without using ngModel

Answer (score 0):

i have this scenario which i have worked, hope it will help

```
 HTML:
 <select class="form-control">
 <option [attr.selected]="index == 2 ? true : null" *ngFor="let segment of segmentation; 
 let index=index;" [ngValue]="index">{{segment.name}}</option>
</select>

TS:
segmentation = [
{ "name": "name 1", "columns": [ { "index": 0}]},
{ "name": "name 2", "columns": [{"index": 1}]},
{ "name": "name 3","columns": [ { "index": 2}]}
]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response,as per this logic every option in second position is selecting right.

Comment: third position will be selected default

Answer (score 0):

With reactive forms, the `selected` attribute is completely ignored, so what you need to do, is to set the value to your form control instead, which can be found by use `.find()` and remove the `selected` from your template.

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    controlFordropdwn: ['']
  });
  let item = this.dropdown.find(x => x.value === x.selected);
  this.myForm.controls.controlFordropdwn.setValue(item.value)
 }
```

Now your select will work correctly.

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztx1ss?file=app/app.component.ts)**